# Stop moving when let go key

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to move Left and Right and whenever I let go of the right arrow it keeps moving right and same with the left side of things. I have been messing around with this and cant figure it out.

```
import pygame

# Intialize the pygame
pygame.init()

# create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

# Player
PlayerHealth = 100
Playerinven = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
playerImg = pygame.image.load('001-alien.png')

# Player Movment
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
XLlabel = False
XRlabel = False
playerX_change = 0
def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x , y))

# Game Loop
running = True
while running:

    # RGB - Red,Green,Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                XLlabel = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                XRlabel = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                XLlabel = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                XRlabel = False
        if XLlabel == True and XRlabel == True:
            playerX_change = 0
        elif XLlabel == True:
            playerX_change = -0.3
        elif XRlabel == True:
            playerX_change = 0.3
        elif XLlabel == False and XRlabel == False:
            player_change = 0
    playerX += playerX_change
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    if playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

This is my first time trying to make a game so it is kinda stressing me out XD

Answer (score 1):

### Error:

- You have written `player_change = 0` where there must be `playerX_change = 0`.

### Code:

```
# Player
PlayerHealth = 100
Playerinven = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
playerImg = pygame.image.load('001-alien.png')

# Player Movment
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
XLlabel = False
XRlabel = False
playerX_change = 0
def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x , y))

# Game Loop
running = True
while running:

    # RGB - Red,Green,Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                XLlabel = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                XRlabel = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                XLlabel = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                XRlabel = False
        if XLlabel == True and XRlabel == True:
            playerX_change = 0
        elif XLlabel == True:
            playerX_change = -0.3
        elif XRlabel == True:
            playerX_change = 0.3
        elif XLlabel == False and XRlabel == False:
            playerX_change = 0    #just a small error you have written player_change = 0
    playerX += playerX_change
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    if playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Good catch.....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cause of your problem but your handling of the keys seems a little "tortured".

For a start, you should generally never use `if XLlabel == True`, preferring instead the more succinct `if XLlabel`.

The key handling can then be made something like:

```py
# Initial left/right key state flags.

left_down, right_down = False, False

for event in pygame.event.get():
    # Process events, keys up/down sets flags.

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            left_down = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            right_down = True

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            left_down = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            right_down = False

    # Event processing done, evaluate key states to get velocity.

    velocity = 0
    if left_down:
        velocity -= 0.3
    if right_down:
        velocity += 0.3

    # Adjust player position by velocity.

   ...
```

Comment: That didnt work but thanks for the advice

Comment: @NojoWizard: Bibhav has now solved that bit for you. You would be wise to look into type hinting and the use of tools like pylint and mypy. We use those for our work products (and the larger of my personal products) and they will catch things like this.